# Excel CreateObject InternetExplorer: Object creation by ActiveX Component not possible

Tags: excel, internet-explorer-11, createobject, vba

I have an intranet web app (Java, Talend Open Studio) which creates an Excel 2013 XLSM with a simple macro.

Depending on user selection, the xlsm contains, besides other data, between 0 and 15 links to another intranet web app with different parameters.

The links are saved as cell values in a hidden sheet.
When user select one of the links in the data sheet, the macro is triggered, which reads the corresponding link cell value and start IE with that link URL.

Since migration to Win10 (64bit) we notice on our PCs 3 different behaviours:

1) On some PCs user can click on links before XLSM is saved

2) On other PCs click on links works only after XLSM has been saved

3) On other PCs click on links does not work at all

Behavior No 1 should be the target and worked like that before the migration.
All PC's have WIN10 and office 2013.
Excel config seems also all the same.

The macro looks like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call OpenURL(Target.Value)
End Sub

Public Sub OpenURL(iHyperLinkName As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

Dim hyperlinkSheet As Worksheet
Dim translatedURL As String
Dim CellComment As String
Dim IEBrowser As Object

'Fetch the URL corresponding to the clicked cell
iHyperLinkName = Replace(iHyperLinkName, vbCr, "")
iHyperLinkName = Replace(iHyperLinkName, vbLf, "")
iHyperLinkName = Replace(iHyperLinkName, vbCrLf, "")
iHyperLinkName = Replace(iHyperLinkName, " ", "")

Set hyperlinkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hyperlinks")

For I = 1 To 15
    CellComment = hyperlinkSheet.Range("A" & I).Comment.Text
    If StrComp(CellComment, iHyperLinkName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      'Create instance
      translatedURL = hyperlinkSheet.Range("A" & I).Value
      Set IEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      IEBrowser.Navigate2 translatedURL
      IEBrowser.Visible = True
      Exit For
    End If
Next I

ErrHandler:
End Sub
```

Debugging shows that in both scenarios No 2 & 3 the problem is in the line

```
Set IEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

When removing the "errorhandler", I get following error (translated from German):

```
Runtime error 429
Object creation by ActiveX Component not possible
```

I tried various other variations to open an URL I found in the net but behaviour is always the same.

Also as it works on various PCs differently, I'm now not sure if it is code related or if there is somewhere an incorrect setting.

The macro is signed by a valid certificate and the supplier has been added into Excel's certification manager on all involved PCs.

I also found various documents on the web telling me to register the missing DLL when this error occurs. But why does it occur on some PC only when XLSM is not saved?

Comment: Did you try adding [Microsoft Internet Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx) as reference?

Comment: Yes. Same behaviour, regardless if MIC is switched ON or OFF.

Comment: After adding Microsoft Internet Controls as reference, can you try `Dim IEBrowser as Internet Explorer` and then  `Set IEBrowser = New InternetExplorer` .

Comment: So far this works after generating the XLSM, edit macro and double click the link. Thanks a lot. We have to trying it out now by changing the XLSM generated by the app directly. Unfortunately this may take some days ...

Comment: OK, finally possible to do the change in the app. And it workds in End2End test. Thanks a lot.